# Using the servlet transport without Spring with Jetty (example from Apache cxf) howto?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jetty, cxf

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html#ServletTransport-UsingtheservlettransportwithoutSpring

Can someone help me, understanding the full example with Jetty in the second code block:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

// Setup the system properties to use the CXFBusFactory not the SpringBusFactory
String busFactory = 
    System.getProperty(BusFactory.BUS_FACTORY_PROPERTY_NAME);
System.setProperty(BusFactory.BUS_FACTORY_PROPERTY_NAME, 
    "org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory");
try {
    // Start up the jetty embedded server
    httpServer = new Server(9000);
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    httpServer.setHandler(contexts);
        ....
```

Must this code block also be in the extended class from CXFNonSpringServlet?
And if so, how to start my Jetty Server with this servlet? Because normally i had this code in my main to start the server:

```
httpServer = new Server(9000);  //Jetty??
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
httpServer.setHandler(contexts);
...
httpServer.start()
```

Or do i pass a reference from the httpServer to the CXFNonSpringServlet?

I am very confused by those little pieces of code without context, can someone help me get the servlet running my jetty server?
Or is there a link to the full code example somewhere (No SVN repository if possible)?

Comment: "Do I pass a reference from the httpServer to the Servlet" can not be right. The ServletContainer (Jetty) knows about the servlets, but not the other way around.